# How to reverse singly linked list - Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hi I am wondering how to go about reversing a singly linked list. From the examples I've looked at so far, the reverse methods have void as their return type and I need one that has singly linked list (SLL) return type. I have an inner class called Node to deal with all the node references.

This is what I have so far:

```
public SLL<E> reverse() {
    Node<E> first = null;
    Node<E> current = this;  // produces compilation error
    while (current != null) {
        Node<E> save = current;
        current = current.next;
        save.next = first;
        first = save;
    }
    return first;
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

Error: incompatible types
  required: myprog.SLL.Node
  found:    myprog.SLL

I am just wondering how I would return the list with type SLL when dealing with Node. I also think my return statement might be wrong.

If you need more code to understand my question, just ask :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is not a coding service. Do your own classwork if you want to actually learn something. If you get stuck, *with your code*, come back to seek help regarding specific coding problems. This question is too broad, and frankly the best thing we can do to help you is to not answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLL should be a class, with a 'head' or 'first' pointer to the first node in the list.

If you're meant to be returning an SLL, that would presumably be a *new* SLL with *new* nodes, copied in reverse-order from the original.

```
public SLL<E> reverse() {
    SLL<E> result = new SLL<E>();

    // copy Nodes into new list, in reverse order.
    //
    Node<E> read = this.first;
    while (read != null) {
        // insert Copy, first;
        Node<E> copy = new Node<E>( read.getItem());
        copy.next = result.first;
        result.first = copy;
        // advance 'Read Position'.
        read = read.next;
    }

    // done.
    return result;
}
```

If you're mutating the original SLL to reverse in-place (haven't checked whether your code even works for that), you shouldn't be returning an SLL result but just void.

Hope this helps.